# How to load from multiple sources to multiple destination dynamically

Tags: sql, ssis

I have more than hundred tables in a linked server (lets say on a sql server 1). I have to perform an initial load, basically a simple dump, by creating duplicate copy of those hundred tables in to sql server 2 destination. I know how to perform data flow task in SSIS to extract data from a source and load it in a destination (creating a table in the destination as well). With more than hundred tables, I would need to create more than hundred data flow tasks which is very time consuming. So I have heard about copying files from source to destination dynamically by looping through and creating variables. Now, how do I do this? Remeber, those hundred tables do no contain similar structure. How can I perform this initial load faster without using multiple data flow task in SSIS. Please, help! Thank you!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: As in if I have created any package? I have absolutely no idea how to work with variables and forloop containers. That is why I am asking about how to perform this. Do not have anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Import and Export Wizard - it can do all those tasks you described in one pass.  You just tell it your Source and Destination and check the tables you want. It generates an SSIS package, which you can save and customize if you want.

It's easiest to find via the Windows Start Menu, under SQL Server [version] / Import and Export Data.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that approach. Do you or anyone else know how to do it dynamically though? I am really trying to learn it that way.. Through creating a package and using forloop/foreachloop container and variables.

Comment: Technically you can create SSIS packages programmatically, via the object model, e.g. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx .  Mostly people seem to get bogged down in the minutae of this and give up.

Comment: So back to import and export, how do I do this with a linked server? If I write a query, I am only able to write it for one table. For example: select * from <linkedserver>.<db>.<schema>.<table> How is it possible to export 300 tables from a linked server?

Comment: You can specify different servers for the Source and Target.  Beyond that you can even mix different flavours (e.g. Oracle to SQL).  The source connection definition will follow your current linked server definition.

Comment: Ok so here's what I am doing: 1) I open the wizard 2) Provide a server name where the linked server is located. Now under the database field, the linked server is not listed because it is a server object. The only way for me to grab information from linked server is via writing a query but how can I write a query for multiple tables?

Comment: Rather than putting the connection details for where the linked server is defined, you should specify the target of the linked server connection. You can get this from SSMS by right-clicking the Linked Server object and choosing Script As.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to automate transferring data from 100+ tables, I would consider using BIML.  BIML is a script language that enables you to generate SSIS packages based on the template you define.  This template in your case may include the creation of the tables (if they do not exist) and the mapping / copying of the source.  You can then wrap the resulting SSIS packages inside another BIML Master package.

It can be a little clunky if you are not using MIST, but its incredibly powerful once you get into it.  A good starting point for you would be [Andy Leonard's Stairway to heaven series](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/100550/) as it provides a step-by-step walk through of moving data from source to target.  After the stairway guide, check out [BIML Script](http://bimlscript.com/)

Comment: Thank you! I am specifically looking to use foreach loop container. Like this article: http://visakhm.blogspot.ru/2013/08/importing-dbf-files-to-ssis.html but I am looking to perform multiple tables load from SQL server1 to multiple source in SQL server2